# PHP value 0 not in $_POST Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I’m trying to send values from an HTML Formular via `$_POST` to a PHP file and work with the values. Everything is working fine, up to the case when I put the number 0 into the HTML field. Then no key or value with my field name is created in my `$_POST` array. I've checked it with `var_dump` and `print_r`, the key I’m looking for is not in the array. I'm using a normal HTML form like this one:

```
<form action="actionfile.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="parameter1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In my PHP file:

```
<?php
  [...]
  $content_array = $_POST;
  var_dump($content_array);
  [...]
?>
```

When I take a look into my Firebug console it is showing me that the 0 is send successfully with POST but it is not in the array.....

And now the really strange thing is, when I'm creating a new file with the same encoding (UTF8/UNIX) the whole thing is working fine. Can somebody tell me why it is not working in my first file?

Comment: Is `var_dump` showing anything?

Comment: I suspect there's more to your script, and it's somehow clearing `$_POST` before this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had an `array_filter()` above my `var_dump`, after removing it the 0 was displayed fine in my `var_dump`. I have aspected that `array_filter()` only kicks emtpy fields, but it kicks fields with a 0 (zero) too

Comment: Make sure to accept your answer when you can. May take a day or so.

Comment: This is almost surely the problem. 0 and '' and null and false will all be true using empty ().  Can you post the arrray_filter callback?

Comment: @Hans i havent declared a callback, only array_filter($array)

Comment: So, is it working for you now? I'm not sure if you've cleared it up. The [docs](http://us3.php.net/array_filter) for array_filter say that if the callback returns true, the item stays in the array. The docs also say that if a callback is not used, entries equalling false are removed. 0 evaluates to false, so it is removed.

Comment: There is also a comment in the User Contrib section of that docs link about how to do this using `strlen` as your callback function.

Comment: Yes it's working for me now, in this case i'm not in need of array_filter it was only at the wrong position

Answer (score 0):

try `$_POST['parameter1']` instead

Comment: If it's not in the array shown by `var_dump`, why would it appear if you access the element by name?

Comment: -1 for the reason @Barmar just said. Make this a comment asking for clarification of whether direct access makes a difference (which it shouldn't given the information known at this time).